# Tauri fs watch plugin only runs watcher callback once

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

I'm experimenting with a Tauri application which monitors changes to local files. I was happy to find the fs-watch plugin, but I can't really make sense of how it works based on the docs.

I tried writing a small test application which monitors just one local file. And it does react to a change, but only the first one.

I'm using the following JS code:

```js
import { watch } from "tauri-plugin-fs-watch-api";

const watchPromise = watch(
  "/home/vincent/test.txt",
  (event) => {
    const { type, payload } = event;
    console.log("Something happened!");
  },
);
```

Building is done as follows: `browserify ./src/app.js -p esmify -o ./public/bundle.js`

And in my HTML page I have:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  const { invoke } = window.__TAURI__.tauri
</script>
```

I would expect the callback to run each time. I'm new to Tauri, so the source code for the plugin doesn't clarify things either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Logging the event details showed that making a change to the file registered a delete event. My guess is that this implies the file no longer had to be watched. There is a short note on this in [the notify docs](https://docs.rs/notify/5.1.0/notify/#editor-behaviour), though there is no mention that this could end the watching altogether.

In any case, I was able to work around the issue by recursively watching the parent folder.